# Vaadin 14: How to update a css style for a component from another thread?

Tags: java, css, animation, vaadin, vaadin-flow

So I have this issue with Vaadin Flow 14, I have a component that uses both `position: static` and `position: absolute` in it's CSS. It also have a cool animation and I needed to use both positions so it doesn't look weird, can take all the screen and can also be scrollable.

It's behavior is the following:

1. Component start with `position: static` in its CSS file (can be scrollable)
2. Click on the component and set `position: absolute` with the method getStyle().set() and it takes all the window
3. Close the component and it goes back to `position: static` so it can be within it's parent and be scrollable

The problem is in Step 3. I set the `position: static` by removing the absolute with getStyle().remove(). I'm doing that from another thread so I can remove the style after the animation is done, in that way it doesn't look weird, has the same flow as when the component was opened and doesn't have that jump cut in it.

The style is removed from the component, however it isn't updated instantly and the component can't be scrolled because it's position is still absolute. However if I click on a link to go to another new tab and go back to the main tab it is now updated and the component is in a static position.

I tried to resolve this by adding @Push on my main class but is doesn't work because I have views inside views and this is a custom component from one of the nested views and it isn't in the main class. I have to be able to update it from the component itself just the way I'm removing the style. I just want the component to wait until the animation is played and THEN remove it's position and this is the only way I could find, any other attempts didn't wait for the animation to be played and just updated itself instantly.

This is the thread code I used to remove the style.

```
new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.getUI().get().access(() -> {
                getContent().getStyle().remove("position");
            });
        }).start();
```

Comment: Vaadin Flow 14 @BasilBourque

Comment: You should store the reference to the UI outside the Thread (in a component itself, for example) and use it. For example, preserve it on the attach event and then re-use in thread.

Comment: Have you verified that the code inside the `access` callback is actually run?

Comment: It behaves just in the same way as I used with the thread @anasmi the code does run, it does remove the component style but it's position isn't static unless I open an external link to another tab and go back to my app tab

Comment: Yes, I did @LeifÅstrand. The code does run, it does remove the component style but it's position isn't static unless I open an external link to another tab and go back to my app tab. Meaning the UI doesn't update instantly, I have to open another tab from the UI in order for it to update the component style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Taking the current UI in an instance and manually setting the push configuration for it.

```
UI currentUI = UI.getCurrent();
currentUI.getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.MANUAL);
```

And adding this at the end of the code in the thread:

```
currentUI.push();
```

Works just exactly like it's supposed to.